# Copying sheet into a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have this VBA  below that works within my workbook where it takes information and populate a sheet within the work book. The issue is that the work book is getting to big and slow and crashes. I want to use the VBA to populate the information into a different workbook instead. Any idea how to do that?

```
Sub AutoAddSheet()



Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("Print Sheets").Range("L1")
Set MyRange = Range("SummTabNames")
'Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))


Dim msg As String

On Error GoTo handler
msg = "Error: You are trying to create a sheet that already exists. You cannot have duplicate sheets. Please clear duplicate sheets to continue."

For Each MyCell In MyRange
Sheets("CCDetailTemplate").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Create a new worksheet as a copy of Sheet number 9 in this example
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 'Renames the new worksheets
Next MyCell

'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'ErrorHandler:
'if (typeof err.Number is (9)

Sheets("acr summary").Select

Exit Sub

handler:
MsgBox (msg)

End Sub
```

Comment: I would recommend looking into Workbook objects and their methods. Particularly how to open and close workbooks with or without saving. Once you assign a specific workbook to a workbook object, _such as `wbk`_ . You can then reference sheets via `wbk.Sheet()`, such as `wbk.Sheets("CCDetailTemplate")`.

Comment: Look into .Move for the individual sheet you want to move.  With just Sheet().Move as the line of code, the sheet is put into a new workbook, which can then be saved.

Comment: I'm not following, can you elaborate this?

Comment: @simon Would you be able to tag in your comment, _who_ you'd like to elaborate? Tagging is done by typing **@** followed by the user's moniker